# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on playing offline videos on my system

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron-3551(2GB RAM). I have dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.Ubuntu 16.04 hangs after 15 minutes while playing videos on VLC player. Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Have you already checked your power management settings?

Comment: Does your entire PC freeze? May you post the results of `lspci | grep vga`?